# Preventing Overwrite When Calling writeToFile:

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory, writetofile

I'm trying to save an image to the disk every time a save button is pressed. This is the code I'm using:

```
NSArray* documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES);

NSString* documentDirectory = [documentDirectories objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* documentDirectoryFilename = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"piclogs"];

[pdfData writeToFile:documentDirectoryFilename atomically:YES];
```

Now, obviously the file to be saved will overwrite the previously saved file every time this method is called. I'm trying to find a way to store every picture taken in there, rather than have it overwritten every time. Does anyone know if there is a simple solution to achieve this? I browsed through the docs but couldn't find anything relevant.

Comment: You need to use a different filename each time you save the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `NSUUID` or `CFUUIDCreate` to create a unique name that you can use for the file.

Answer (score 1):

or you could check if the file with that name exists and if it does don't write to file. Then change the name if you want so you do have a copy of what you may or may not be trying to save.

```
NSArray* documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES);

NSString* documentDirectory = [documentDirectories objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* documentDirectoryFilename = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"piclogs"];
if (![NSURL fileURLWithPath:[self documentsPathForFileName:documentDirectoryFilename]]) {
    [pdfData writeToFile:documentDirectoryFilename atomically:YES];
} else {
    NSString* altName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%d", documentDirectoryFilename, intValue];
    [pdfData writeToFile:altName atomically:YES];
}
```